# How to generate crystal report using mysql database in asp.net 2010

Tags: asp.net, mysql

can any one please help me in generating the crystal reports in visual studio 2010. I am using the mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an article in codeproject will help you

[How to Create a Crystal Report using C# and MySQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14029/How-to-Create-a-Crystal-Report-using-C-and-MySQL)